# Bad value pagination for attribute role on element nav

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation, wai-aria

I'm getting this error in W3C Validation. I'm using HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`

> Bad value pagination for attribute role on element nav.

for

```
<nav class="pagination" role="pagination">
```

Does anybody knows how to solve this or What is the reason behind this? Does W3V Validator not support ARIA ?

Comment: Can't see any trace of a `pagination` role in the ARIA roles specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles And if it is not in the specification it probably means that it is invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) says, `pagination` is a bad value for `nav` element, you can use `navigation` instead. Validate the code below and see it yourself

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <title>Test</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav role="navigation"> </nav>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

From [w3org](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_HTML5_nav_element)

> However, in order to make the structure more accessible to user agents
>   that support ARIA as well as ensuring that user agents that don't
>   support HTML5 can also understand the structure, adding the ARIA
>   role="navigation" is advised.

Comment: For a `nav` element, the only allowed values of `role` are `navigation` (the default, but it is indeed recommended to specify it explicitly) and `presentation` (which removes the semantics of the element in the ARIA sense).

Comment: And in case you're wondering where these rules are written in specs you can find them in the [Using WAI-ARIA in HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#recommendations-table).